# Two way binding in render function in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building an application in `Vuejs` where I'm creating a render function for `input` fields. I'm emitting an `input event` to bind with `v-model`. I can see values are getting assigned while I assign/insert any values, but when I assign the other way i.e. assigning any value to v-model for input fields it shows empty or it shows the placeholder values if it is available

Here is my code:

```
createElement('input', {
    class: 'form-control m-input',
    attrs: { type: this.type, placeholder: this.placeholder },
    on: {
        input: (event) => {
            this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
        }
    }
})
```

In props I have:

```
props: {
    label: String,
    type: String,
    placeholder: String,
},
```

and while declaring components I do:

```
<nits-input
        label="Email"
        type="email"
        placeholder="Enter your email"
        v-model="email"
>
</nits-input>
```

In data I'm trying to assign the values:

```
data() {
    return {
        email: 'test@example.com',
    }
},
```

How can I achieve assigning values to v-model and displaying it inside the respective fields. Help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is really just shorthand for having a `value` prop and emitting an input event.

So in addition to your existing props, you need to add a value one:

```
props: {
    label: String,
    type: String,
    placeholder: String,
    value: String
},
```

Comment: I think we have to bind `attrs: { type: this.type, placeholder: this.placeholder, value: this.value },` also